# How to get ALL used addresses of a Daedalus wallet (byron era) with cardano-cli

Tags: wallet, address, byron

i'm looking for a way to get ALL used addresses of a Daedalus wallet (byron era) with the cardano-cli.

Background:
Daedalus is not showing up the used addresses combined under a "Recieve" tab, like it does for Shelly wallets. One can only click through all transactions an guess what addresses belong to the wallet. This is pretty time consuming and error prone, especially when there are transactions with multiple out-/inputs.

My hope is, to utilize the cardano-cli for that purpose. I already managed to install the cli and set it up to use the Daedalus socket. But further i didn't come. Can someone please hive me a hint where to start.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly using the `cardano-cli`. You can use a third party tool to do this, like [blockfrost](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D%7E1mirs/get).

A simple curl command using your free project id would look like this.

```
curl -H "project_id: REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT ID" https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/accounts/REPLACE WITH YOUR STAKE ADDRESS/addresses
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but byron era wallets don't have a staking address.